# Direct proportionality with negative constant of proportionality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I got in trouble trying to help with the concept of inverse proportionality. The idea is simple, and upon looking up on-line the formal algebraic formula it seems like it is simply

$$c = xy$$

with x and y being variables, and c a constant.

On the other hand $y= cx$ is a direct proportionality relationship between these two variables.

The question is whether $y=-cx,$ i.e. when the slope is negative, there is a term different from direct and inverse proportionality.

The issue arises when you try to teach inverse proportionality as "the higher the variable x, the lower the variable y", which is true both for $y= c/x$ (inverse proportionality), as for $y= - c x$ (direct proportionality with a negative slope). Also, it is difficult to come up with examples of the latter.