# Is being directly negatively proportional same as being inversely proportional?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

If I have the proportionality
$$x\propto-y$$
It suggests that x increases with $-y$ and since there's a negative symbol present it would mean that the lower the value of $y$ the higher the value of $x$...so does this still qualify as directly proportional?

It does seem to be different from $x\propto\frac{1}y$ so I guess it's not inversely proportional?

The direct relation of $y$ with $x$ sounds wrong to be called directly proportional, so what exactly is a negative proportionality called if not being the same as inversely proportional?

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559368/direct-proportionality-with-negative-constant-of-proportionality. Related?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> _Negatively proportional_ seems self-explanatory; as you say, that's not the same as _inversely proportional_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Actually, $$x=5y$$ and $$x=-5y$$ each implies that
   $$x\propto y,$$ which means that for some non-identically-zero function $k$ of variables that don't have another dependence on $x$ or $y,$ $$x=ky.$$
   So, the negative sign in $\:\:x\propto-y\:\:$ is in fact redundant.
   This reinforces the fact that **‘negative proportionality’ is a
   type of direct proportionality**.

   To disambiguate the former from *inverse* proportionality and negative *inverse* proportionality, we might say that **$x$ is directly proportional but opposite in sign
   to $y.$**
2. **Negative direct proportionality** and inverse proportionality are not equivalent: as $x$ approaches infinity, the magnitude of $y$ approaches infinity in the former but approaches zero in the latter.
3. > $$x\propto-y$$
   > This direct relation of $y$ with $x$ sounds wrong to be called directly proportional

   You're saying that

   - $x$ is directly proportional to $-y,$

   rather than saying that

   - $x$ is directly proportional to $y,$

   so how is there any anomaly? The former is analogous to using the
   word “add” in the instruction

   - add $-3$ to $7.$

Comment: Thanks, so is 'negatively proportional' a proper term just like 'inversely proportional' - if it is then how come almost no one ever uses that despite negative proportionalities not being rare?

Comment: @Nirabhra "Directly proportional but opposite in sign" also works. (Replacing an earlier comment, since it was too late to edit it.)

Comment: @ryang Feel free to use the phrase in the answer; I'm almost sure I'm just remembering something I've seen elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that they are not the same. If something is negatively proportional, its graph may be a  line going from upper left to lower right. There is a negative constant involved $\quad -\infty\lt c \lt 0\quad$ so the angle with the x-axis  may be
$\quad \large{\dfrac{\pi}{2}
\lt\alpha\lt\pi}.\quad$ If something is inversely proportional, sign is irrelevant and its graph may be one, two, or four ski slopes with both horizontal and vertical  asymptotes.